# Conditional rendering with optionals in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Coming from a React background it's easy to only render a view if a value is defined. It looks like this:

```
function Component ({ profile }) {
  return (
    <div>{profile && <div>{profile.name}}</div>
  )
}
```

But I'm finding this pattern much more difficult to replicate in SwiftUI. Ideally we could use conditional unwrapping in our Views, but this doesn't currently work. The only solution I've been able to figure out is really inelegant:

```swift
struct ProfileView : View {
    var profile: Profile?

    var body : some View {
        if let profile = profile {
            return Text("profile: \(profile.bio)")
        }  else {
            return Text("")
        }
    }
}

struct LayoutView : View {
    @State var profile: Profile?
    var body : some View {
        Group {
            ProfileView(profile: profile)
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: fetch)

    // fetch method 
}
```

Does anyone have some better strategies for conditional rendering using optional values?

Comment: Replace the whole `if let` block with `Text(profile != nil ? "profile: \(profile!.bio)" : "")`. Nothing specific to SwiftUI here.

Comment: Oh man, I never even considered using the ! operator. I'm a total newbie when it comes to Swift.... obviously, heh.

Answer (score 7):

You can go the other way around using `map` to take care of the optional with something like this:

```
struct ProfileView : View {
    var profile: Profile?

    var body : some View {
        profile.map { Text("profile: \($0.bio)") }
    }
}
```

(`$0` is your unwrapped `profile` in this example.)

If you need the else case:

```
profile.map { Text($0.bio) } ?? Text("Not available")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
struct LayoutView : View {
    @State var profile: Profile?
    var body : some View {
        Group {
            if profile != nil {
                ProfileView(profile: profile!)
            }
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: fetch)

    // fetch method 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem closely related to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `@Binding` in a child view `ProfileView` to ensure the text will be in sync with `profile` data as it changes. This is how I would do it all:

```
struct Profile {
    var bio: String = "Biography"
}

struct ProfileView : View {
    @Binding var profile: Profile?
    private var profileText: String {
        get {
            profile == nil ? "" : "profile: " + profile!.bio
        } // set part is not necessary if we don't set the text from the view
        set {
            self.profile?.bio = newValue
        }
    }

    var body : some View {
        Text(profileText)
    }
}

struct LayoutView : View {
    @State var profile: Profile?
    var body : some View {
        Group {
            ProfileView(profile: $profile)
        }
    }
}

// check it via preview
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LayoutView(profile: Profile())
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this need to be so many lines of code? Is there not a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there are ways to answer shorter but then the solution matches the question and is easy to take play with it. More elegant way is to declare `@Bindable` var right away and move get-set logic into it on creation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3363053-init